# Comment transposer/traduire le « perfunctory statement » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs, formulation-idiomatique, registre-soutenu

> He made/issued a [**perfunctory**](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/perfunctory) statement supporting the mayor.
> (ex. sur [The Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/perfunctory))

Le *TBD* dit de l'adjectif qu'il est « used to describe something that is done without energy or enthusiasm because of habit or because it is expected » et d'un registre *formal*.

Quelles sont des manières de transposer l'adjectif en français et de traduire cette phrase ?

Comment: Du moment que tu ne traites pas les gens de "ridicule" et que tu ne les insultes pas dès que tu peux...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"He made/issued a perfunctory statement supporting the mayor" pourrait se traduire par :
Il a fait une déclaration **de pure forme** pour soutenir le maire.

Discours ou actions  "de pure forme" indique que discours ou actions respectent les apparences ou les convenances, mais n'ont guère d'effet notoire.

Dans cet exemple, "de pure forme" (english translation : rhetorical) semble mieux adapté que la traduction usuelle de  "perfunctory", à savoir "superficiel".

On peut aussi écrire "de pure convenance".

Si on veut dire que la déclaration a été faite à contrecoeur, on pourra utiliser l"expression **du bout des lèvres** (english translation : reluctantly)

Si on veut indiquer un manque d'enthousiasme, ce pourrait être :  **sans conviction**.